# How to make a user "likes" a page in facebook using Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-graph-api

I am already making the user give the permission for the application and it is already attending the user to a certain event. Now I need to make the user "enter" a community.
I guess that would be it "Liking" the page, right?

How can I do that?
using the /me/likes I get the list of pages that it liked, and from my own profile I can see the page that I need to make other people like.

Thanks!
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and you can't.

Its easily done by this php code:

```
 $facebook = FacebookInit();
 $facebook->api("/$InterestId/likes", "post", 
    array("access_token" => $AccessToken));
```

but facebook isn't allowing applications to "Like" in the user's behalf.
see http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/10/08/causes-whitelisted-like-pages-2/